# how can I change my default scrollbar to custom for Object tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just want to set a new custom scrollbar for my pdf viewer (which i show with in object tag) but the custom scroll css cannot affect the object tag, why its happening ? for all other tags the custom scroll css is affected and i have no problem with that but only for object tag i need a custom scrollbar.

I tried the custom scrollbar css code but its not working for object tag but for all other works fine.

```js
var openFile = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var dataURL = reader.result;
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.data = dataURL;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<input type='file' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<object id='output'></object>
```

[image]

I just want a custom scroll design for that pdf viewer object.

Comment: can you share the relevant css, please?

Comment: added, check now

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display: block;` to your `object` CSS solved the issue on my side.

My example is a little different, I added some content because, I have no output. But your syntax is correct and the scrollbar will show.

```js
var openFile = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var dataURL = reader.result;
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.data = dataURL;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
};
```

```css
object {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
}
object::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

object::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

object::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #D62929;
}
```

```html
<input type='file' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<object id='output'>
  <div class="example-content">example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example<br>example</div>
</object>
```

Comment: No its now working for object tag where i load pdf document, i share my screenshot what i get, check that

Comment: 'No its now working' what do you mean? Not working or is working?

Comment: it means, it will only works on all div elements and body tag but not work for the object tag (see the screenshot) , what i get for object tag is default scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 0px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    background: #ffffff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: var(--light-grey1);
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```